# Joining an Embedded Entity's row to POJO in Room Dao

Tags: android, android-sqlite, inner-join, android-room

I'm querying for a POJO using Room Persistance Library (v2.0.0). I've all those entities in different tables (bookentries, categories,...). 
I'm trying to combine a BookEntryEntity with a Category that matches the BookEntry's `category_id`.

```
class BookEntry(
        @Embedded var entity: BookEntryEntity = BookEntryEntity(),
        @Embedded(prefix = 'cg_') var category: Category? = null,
        contacts: List<Contact.ContactEntity>? = null
) : Parcelable {

    @Relation(
            entity = Contact.ContactEntity::class,
            parentColumn = 'id',
            entityColumn = 'bookentry_id'
    )
    var embeddedContacts: List<Contact.ContactEntity>? = contacts

    //...

    @Entity(tableName = 'bookentries')
    data class BookEntryEntity(
            @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = 'id') var id: Long = 0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = 'title') var title: String = "",
            @ColumnInfo(name = 'date') var date: Date = Date(),
            @ColumnInfo(name = 'value') var value: Double = 0.0,
            @ColumnInfo(name = 'notes') var notes: String = "",
            @ColumnInfo(name = 'entrytype') var entryType: Int = Type.Earning,
            @ColumnInfo(name = Reference.CATEGORY_ID) var categoryId: Long? = null
    )

}
```

The Embedded Entity `Category` is not joined automatically.

```
@Entity(tableName = 'categories')
data class Category(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = 'id') val id: Long = 0, @ColumnInfo(name = 'name') var name: String = "")
```

I tried to join it the following way:

```
@Dao
interface BookEntryDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM bookentries INNER JOIN categories ON bookentries.cg_id = categories.id WHERE categories.id == bookentries.category_id ORDER BY bookentries.date DESC")
    fun getBookEntries(): LiveData<List<BookEntry>>
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error:

> error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
>   missing database (no such column: bookentries.cg_id)

But if I remove the inner join, I receive the following warning:

> warning:  at.guger.moneybook.data.model.BookEntry has some fields
>   [cg_id, cg_name] which are not returned by the query.

How to join the query correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@Dao
interface BookEntryDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM bookentries INNER JOIN categories ON bookentries.category_id = categories.id ORDER BY bookentries.date DESC")
    fun getBookEntries(): LiveData<List<BookEntry>>
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, I've the BookEntryEntity with the correct `category_id` but I want to load the category information (the name) from another table in this transaction. Have a look at my edited post please.

Comment: That's what this SQL statement does :/. The class `BookEntry` is not an entity, so when using @Embedded, I would remove the prefix value.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, my fault... But now there is another warning:
The query returns some columns [name] which are not use by at.guger.moneybook.data.model.BookEntry. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. at.guger.moneybook.data.model.BookEntry has some fields [cg_id, cg_name] which are not returned by the query.
Do you have an idea to solve that?

Comment: You can 1. alias category columns e.g. `SELECT bookentries.*, categories.id as cg_id, [other columns...] FROM bookentries INNER JOIN categories ON bookentries.category_id = categories.id ORDER BY bookentries.date DESC` OR 2. remove prefix = 'cg_' from @Embedded.